Solana Program - Rust Borsh serialization issue
Solana Program - Rust Borsh serialization issue
Here is the solana program [ethereum terms this is called a smart contract]:
use solana_program::{
    account_info::AccountInfo,
    entrypoint,
    entrypoint::ProgramResult,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
    msg,
    program_error::ProgramError,
    program_pack::{Pack, Sealed},
};

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct SimpleData {
    pub value: u64,
}

impl Sealed for SimpleData {}

impl Pack for SimpleData {
    const LEN: usize = 8; // u64 is 8 bytes

    fn unpack_from_slice(src: &[u8]) -> Result<Self, ProgramError> {
        let value = u64::from_le_bytes(src.try_into().map_err(|_| ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData)?);
        Ok(SimpleData { value })
    }

    fn pack_into_slice(&self, dst: &mut [u8]) {
        let value_bytes = self.value.to_le_bytes();
        dst.copy_from_slice(&value_bytes);
    }
}

entrypoint!(process_instruction);

pub fn process_instruction(
    _program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    msg!("Instruction data length: {}", instruction_data.len());

    // Validate the instruction data length
    if instruction_data.len() != 8 {
        msg!("Invalid instruction data length");
        return Err(ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData);
    }

    let value = u64::from_le_bytes(instruction_data.try_into().map_err(|_| ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData)?);
    msg!("Received value: {}", value);

    let account = &accounts[0];
    let mut data = account.try_borrow_mut_data()?;

    SimpleData { value }.pack_into_slice(&mut data);

    Ok(())
}

Here is my test script written in Javascript on Nodejs 20
const {
    Connection,
    sendAndConfirmTransaction,
    Keypair,
    Transaction,
    SystemProgram,
    PublicKey,
    TransactionInstruction,
    LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
} = require("@solana/web3.js");

async function main() {
    const connection = new Connection("http://localhost:8899", "confirmed");
    const payer = Keypair.generate();

    const programId = new PublicKey('86MMZzQYxEU49ixmVkeP8p864mgKbaNQPWe2gq4Crw2P');

    const airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(payer.publicKey, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);
    await connection.confirmTransaction(airdropSignature);

    const storeAccount = Keypair.generate();
    const createAccountIx = SystemProgram.createAccount({
        fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
        newAccountPubkey: storeAccount.publicKey,
        lamports: await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(8), // Only 8 bytes needed for u64
        space: 8,
        programId: programId,
    });

    const createAccountTx = new Transaction().add(createAccountIx);
    await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, createAccountTx, [payer, storeAccount]);

    const valueToSet = 42n; // Using BigInt for 64-bit integer
    const buffer = Buffer.alloc(8);
    buffer.writeBigUInt64LE(valueToSet); // Writing the 64-bit integer as a Little Endian buffer

    const setIx = new TransactionInstruction({
        keys: [{ pubkey: storeAccount.publicKey, isSigner: false, isWritable: true }],
        programId: programId,
        data: buffer, // Directly sending the 64-bit integer as a buffer
    });

    const setTx = new Transaction().add(setIx);
    await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, setTx, [payer]);

    console.log('Transaction successful and value set.');
}

main().then(() => process.exit()).catch(console.error);

and this is the error when i run the test against the solana program :
PS C:\source\testsolana\node> node .\solana_complex_structure.js Starting Solana Program test script... Generated new keypair. Public key: HDXaegVA9ENJKeg8dmKm1HhuA69NssBGNQJE4tt4BEg7 Requesting airdrop... Airdrop confirmed. Testing Sign Instruction... Error in main function: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'writeUIntLE') at UInt.encode (C:\source\node_modules\buffer-layout\lib\Layout.js:578:7) at Structure.encode (C:\source\node_modules\buffer-layout\lib\Layout.js:1263:26) at testSignInstruction (C:\source\testsolana\node\solana_complex_structure.js:60:27) at main (C:\source\testsolana\node\solana_complex_structure.js:41:11) at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) 

I am running a local test validator:
Config File: /home/kmukherjee/.config/solana/cli/config.yml
RPC URL: http://172.20.116.234:8899
WebSocket URL: ws://172.20.116.234:8900/ (computed)
Keypair Path: /home/kmukherjee/.config/solana/id.json
Commitment: confirmed


const buffer is undefined, fix it.
